# Fake custom object as a target DOM element for jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, dom

I have made a custom dialogue window class and want it to represent a DOM object for the jQuery to be able to apply selectors on it. I want to associate a dialogue instance with the DOM element it creates. What should I do to make this code work?

```
var instances_counter = 0
var dialogue = function()
{
    this.id = ++instances_counter
    $("body").append("<div id='dlg" + this.id + "'>[[[<div class='msg'>Message.</div>]]]</div>")
}
var dlg1 = new dialogue()
var dlg2 = new dialogue()
// What behaviour I want to implement:
$(".msg",dlg2).css("color","red") 
alert(dlg2 instanceof dialogue) // This must alert 'true'.
// To do the same as:
// $("#dlg2 .msg").css("color","red")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a243uxmt/2

Comment: Could you explain clearly, what dialogue instance you need to associate.

Comment: Each dialogue instance that is created by a constructor function I need to associate with the div element that it appends to a body when being created.